# How to get exponent with imaginary number in python

Tags: python, exponent

I am doing fft shift and I got

p = [image]

How  to get constant d if I know all other variables? I tried to use math.log1p but it keeps giving me "Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part".

I get `p = 0.0656073874479-0.399102149653j`, it can be represented as formula above where `N = 20000`, `k = 1`.

I want to calculate what d is.

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear. The image is too small. Do add some sample inputs, the code you've tried, the errors you've got and the output you expect.

Comment: I added more detail. This is what I get so far. I simply just want to calculate d and it is in an imaginary part of an exponent. Thank you!

Comment: How would you hand-calculate this `d`? At the moment, it looks like you are stuck with the mathematics of it rather than programming it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `cmath` to get some branch of the complex logarithm:

```
cmath.log(p)*N/(-2*cmath.pi*1j*k)
```

Comment: Is "i" supposed to be "1j". It says i is undefined?

Comment: I tried to use "1j" instead of i and the output I get is (4481.37690134-2881.35892394j). I think it should be a real number?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly... So if the solution is 4481.37690134-2881.35892394j, I need to take 4481.37690134 as the result? Could you explain more about the reason for this?

Comment: @ZigZagZebra Wait a sec let me check up on this I'm not sure about what I said.